# Is it possible to retrieve the message from queue present on MSMQ into SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jms

I am novice about MSMQ and SSIS. 
Currently i am using the JMS service to populate the information on MSMQ. Till there i have populated the message in queue under MSMQ queue. 
Is there any way to import those queue body information into SSIS packages. How can i be able to configure the SSIS with MSMQ and import the message from queue.

Comment: Theres a related blog article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/06/10/reading-msmq-from-within-ssis-packages.aspx)

Comment: @StuartLC I have an scenario in which the client sends the message using JMS services. In the above posted link, we will create the send and recieve queue. But is there a way to connect that JMS with the SSIS to populate on the queue. I have gone through different sites but was unable to get a solutions. The main problem currently lies is that i am unable to connect JMS that carries the data information to populate on MSMQ queue.

Comment: Have you or have you not managed to put data on the MSMQ? You are saying two different things